# Polar transform in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Turning a line into a ring is a simple task in graphics programs such as GIMP:

[image: Filter ⇒ Distorts ⇒ Polar Coordinates]
<sub>(source: [adamhaskell.net](http://adamhaskell.net/img/transform.png))</sub>

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to produce the same effect in CSS.

So I worked out the following:

- The above algorithm maps `x` to `r` and `y` to `θ`
- To do this, `x` is scaled to the range of `[0,w/2]`, with `w` being the width of the image
- Also, `y` is scaled to the range of `[0,2π]`
- To transform polar coordinates back into Cartesian: `xc = rp*cos(θp)` and `yc = rp*sin(θp)`
- The result is then translated so the origin is in the centre of the image.
- So we have:

```
x' = (x/2)*cos(y/h*2π) + w/2;  
y' = (x/2)*sin(y/h*2π) + h/2;
```

This is all fine and dandy, but how can I produce such a transform in CSS? Presumably none of the keywords are useful, so it has to be a Matrix transform. Well, I have no idea how to build a matrix from the two equations above, much less how to represent it in a CSS transform.

Can anyone help me on this last step?

Comment: +1 for this interesting question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never worked with CSS transform matrices, but I think what you want is **not possible**.
Using transform matrices you do a **linear transformation**. Linear transformations ALWAYS **map a straight line to a straight line** or to 0. [Take a look at Wikipedia for more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation).

So it's impossible to map a straight line to a circle using matrices.

Comment: Best answer. Rather than presenting some convoluted method, just a simple "You can't do it, this is why" is perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

At least you can make 2 symmetrical third order Bezier curve
Using

Y(t) = (t^3,t^2,t,1) * M * (P0,P1,P2,P3)

t - time

P0 - P3 control points coordinates. This vector must be vertical.I do not know how to make vertical vector in this editor.

Y(t) - curve coordinate

M - 4*4 matrix row  1 (-1,3,-3,1) row 2 (3,-6,-3,0) row 3 (-3,3,0,0) row 4 (1,0,0,0)

Now you need only a function what defines control points from your line coordinate.

Comment: That is answer to post about linear transformations and matrices. Though multiplying by t^3 is not a linear transformation.

Comment: The question is about solving this problem in CSS. Nowhere in your post is CSS mentioned.